# Error c2664: GetDC: невозможно преобразовать параметр из System::IntPtr в HWND

Tags: windows, c++-cli, visual-c++

```
HDC fhan = GetDC(this->Handle);
```

Visual Studio 2012 Express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смотрим MSDN:

```
HDC GetDC(
   _In_  HWND hWnd
);
```

Получается, Вы передаете в ф-цию `System::IntPtr`. Это часом не C++/CLI? А почему это не отмечено? Т.к. в стандартном C++ нет `System::IntPtr`. Вариантов решения проблемы несколько.

1. Переделать `this->Handle` в `HWND`. `Handle` - явно член написанного Вами класса.
2. попробуйте так: `GetDC((HWND)this->Handle.ToPointer())` или
3. `GetDC(static_cast<HWND>(this->Handle.ToPointer()))`.